# Solr Request Handlers and Query Parsers

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr. Please help me with following queries:

1. What is the difference between a request handler and a query parser?
   I'm thinking it's that when a query is sent through URL in solr, at first the query is parsed using the Query parser. Request handler then takes the parsed query and searches and presents the response according to request handler parameters. Is this Correct?
2. What is the default query parser and default request handler in Solr?
3. Parameter deftype is used to specify parser and qt for request handlers right?
   I wrote this query
   `select?q=features:power%20features:latency&deftype=dismax`
   which works, but `select?q=features:power%20features:latency&qt=dismax` does not.

Here is my `requestHandler`

```
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="defType">dismax< /str>
  <str name="echoParams">explicit< /str>
  <float name="tie">0.01< /float>
  <str name="qf">text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4< /str>
  <str name="pf">text^0.2 features^1.1 name^1.5 manu^1.4 manu_exact^1.9< /str>
  <str name="bf">popularity^0.5 recip(price,1,1000,1000)^0.3< /str>
  <str name="fl">id,name,price,score< /str>
  <str name="mm">2<-1 5<-2 6<90%< /str>
  <int name="ps">100< /int>
  <str name="q.alt">*:*< /str>
 <!--  example highlighter config, enable per-query with hl=true
  -- >
  < str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
 <!--  for this field, we want no fragmenting, just highlighting
  -- >
  < str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0< /str>
 <!--  instructs Solr to return the field itself if no query terms are
          found
  -- >
  <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name< /str>
  <str name="f.text.hl.fragmenter">regex< /str>
 <!--  defined below
  -->
  < /lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default request handler is the one with default="true" parameter in SolrConfig.xml (SearchHandler, if you haven't changed that).

Request handler handles requests, so it is a starting point for every request, which means that request handler uses/calls query parser (either the one specified by the url or default one) as its first step.

You want to get:
 1. Documents with "power latency" as the phrase?
 2. Or docs with both terms anywhere in a doc?
 3. Or docs with either of those terms?

Try like this:
 1. select?q=features:"power latency"&qt=dismax
 2. select?q=features:power+features:latency&qt=dismax&mm=2
 3. select?q=features:power+features:latency&qt=dismax&mm=1

More info on [DisMaxQParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin).

Comment: But why isnt select?q=features:power%20features:latency&qt=dismax working.My Solr Config file has mm=2 as its default value.And I have 6 documents with power in 2 documents and latency in rest of the 4.None of them have both power and latency.
So with deftype=dismax it gave me 6 documents which is correct.But when I used qt=dismax it doesnt show any result.mm=2 by default !!!!!!
What is the difference then between deftype and qt???

Comment: One more question.When we are able to give both deftype=dismax and qt=dismax it means that dismax is both parser and request handler.Is that right??
May I know what are the other parsers in Solr,also request handlers.

Comment: Please post your <requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler"> from solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Since the no of characters are exceeeding,I posted it as an answer!!

Comment: qt vs defType is not a question of preference, it's a question of purpose. 
"qt" is used to select the requestHandler instance.  "defType" tells that 
requestHandler what you want the default QParser to be for the "q" param